# How to join a google map div with a contact form through bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, grid

Hello all im trying to place a google map div next to a contact form I have but I'm kinda lost due to the grid placement.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-6 offset-xl-2 py-5">

    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action=".." role="form">

        <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_need">Please specify your need </label>
                        <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">...</option>
                            <option value="2">...</option>
                            <option value="3">...</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                </div>
            </div>
                    
                </form>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- row-->
    </div>
    <!-- container-->
```

And this is a map script I found online.

```
<div id="googleMap" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>

        <script>
        function myMap() {
        var mapProp= {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5,
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
        }
        </script>
        
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
```

Now I understand I need to place it into another grid to the left of the form but my mind is fried. this is my first time working with grids and it took me way too long to get to this. anyone has any idea to help me?? basically I'm looking to have the map on the left and the contact form on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you trying to put them in a single row, you should wrap both of them under the same `row` class and specify how much space should they fill in this particular case I just give both of them `col-6` which in bootstrap 4 and above each item with this class will occupy half of the row space from `0px` to whatever you can modify it to whatever you want by reading more about bootstrap grid system [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/). Also if you want it to be responsive you need to avoid giving your map element manual `width`, for showing it you just need to specify its height. It can be `100%` instead of precise height to fill the available space.

```css
.row {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 py-5">

      <form id="contact-form" method="post" action=".." role="form">

        <div class="controls">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_need">Please specify your need </label>
                <select id="form_need" name="need" class="form-control" required="required" data-error="Please specify your need.">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="1">...</option>
                  <option value="2">...</option>
                  <option value="3">...</option>
                  <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="col-6 py-5">
      <div id="googleMap"></div>

      <script>
        function myMap() {
          var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
          };
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
        }
      </script>

      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row-->
</div>
<!-- container-->
```